# Get latest tweet using Tweetsharp on Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, tweetsharp

I only want to get a latest tweet to my Windows Phone Apps using Tweetsharp. below is what I have done:

1. Installing Tweetsharp using Nuget Package Manager.
2. Registering my apps to Twitter Developer Site.
3. Get Consumer key, Consumer Secret, token, and token secret.
4. Initializing TwitterService using that 4 keys.

Then, what is next? are there any mistakes of my steps above? I am really confused.

Comment: Showing some code would help you to get an answer.

Comment: if your concern is to get tweets, just use `"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=from: + ID + &since:2012-01-01` nothing more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for tweetsharp is available on the [wiki](https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp).

The best method is [statuses/user_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline) :

> Returns a collection of the most recent Tweets posted by the user
>   indicated by the screen_name or user_id parameters

You have all the prerequisites. Let's code !

A piece of Xaml

```
<!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tweetList">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Text="{Binding Text}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  Text="{Binding CreatedDate}" FontSize="12" FontStyle="Italic"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock  Text="Tweet List" FontSize="26" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" />
    <ListBox 
       Height="650"               
        Margin="0,20,0,0"
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
      ItemTemplate="{StaticResource tweetList}"
      x:Name="tweetList">
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

and a piece of C#

```
// Constructor
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var service = new TwitterService("yourconsumerKey", "yourconsumerSecret");
    service.AuthenticateWith("youraccessToken", "youraccessTokenSecret");

    service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() { ScreenName = "SCREENNAME" }, (ts, rep) =>
        {
            if (rep.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                //bind
                this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { tweetList.ItemsSource = ts; });
            }
        });
}
```

that's all !

Comment: Nice Answer But Now i am Getting  Error (215 Bad Authantecation Error) as Response ...is this a problam with that Api v1 is retire and Now api v1.1 is Available