# Get Latest Tweets from Users home_timeline Using Tweetsharp with Api v1.1

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, tweetsharp

Im Working on Windows Phone App in that i need to get User Home_timeline Tweets to My App and Show in ListBox 
So how can i get Latest Tweets from Users home_timeline Using Tweet-sharp (json) Using Api v1.1
Because API v1 Retirement is Complete
https://dev.twitter.com/blog/api-v1-is-retired

Comment: Refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206726/reading-twitter-feed/17206811#17206811 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169571/get-latest-tweet-using-tweetsharp-on-windows-phone-7

Comment: Hay Im going with this Ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169571/get-latest-tweet-using-tweetsharp-on-windows-phone-7 But Im getting confused with ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions()

Comment: You can just play around with different method overloads.