# Does twitter api 1.1 work for windows phone

Tags: c#, twitter, windows-phone, twitter-oauth, tweetsharp

I need to get my twitter Home_timeline tweets from the last few days on my windows phone app. Im trying different examples with Tweetsharp [Tweetsharp Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17169571/get-latest-tweet-using-tweetsharp-on-windows-phone-7) and with OAuth1.1 .

I am login to twitter but not able to post and retriev tweets from Twitter. I tried using with Api v1.1 but I am receiving Error 215

Can anyone say what is a perfect example to Get Home_timeline Tweets to our App with Api v1.1?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to implement a server side based solution to leverage Twitter's API 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Twitter API 1.1 for some time now without any problem.
Check if the authentication header is created properly. One problem I faced was with timestamp parameter. Since it is included in signature, a wrong device time would result in failure.
Also see if your twitter app has proper permissions set (read+write).

Comment: Do You Have Any Perfect Working Example to get User Home_timeline.

Comment: Use this: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline.  I am not using TweetSharp.